# Most efficient way to generate lists that count by powers of 10 in Python?

Tags: python

I've come up with the following function, which does exactly what I was wanting it to do:

```
from math import log10

def count_by_powers_of_ten(input_number):
    if input_number == 0:
        return [0]
    list_of_numbers = [0, 1]
    current_number  = 1
    while current_number < input_number:
        power_of_ten = int(log10(current_number))
        increment_by = 10 ** power_of_ten
        current_number += increment_by
        list_of_numbers.append(current_number)
    return list_of_numbers
```

For example, if my input is 1000, I will get:

```
count_by_powers_of_ten(1000)

>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
```

So, from 0-10, I'm counting by 1s; from 10-100, I'm counting by 10s, from 100-1000, I'm counting by 100s.

But I'm curious if this function could be made more efficient or if there are off-the-shelf methods for getting this sort of output?

Comment: This may fall under the use case of "premature optimization," but you don't really need to recompute the current power of ten. You could just remember it. I'd probably use a generator expression. I'd probably use itertools.repeat to control the length.

Comment: Since you have working code but want improvement suggestions, you might also post on [codereview.se]

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the end condition, but the rest holds, especially the part about premature optimization.

Comment: Are you sure your code's supposed to generate `2000` when the input's `1001`?

Comment: Mike: it's certainly a little inelegant, but that matches what I was expecting for cases like that. I just wanted the next element that is greater than or equal to the input, following the "powers of 10" pattern. It could be the case that my use case will make it unnecessary to generate that next element, though, especially when it's so distant from the original input.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same results with a generator, which has the benefit of not needing to calculate the log of a number. That being said, this is effectively what you have already, and you probably won't see any performance benefit out of it.

```py
def base_ten_log_counter():
    base_factor = 1
    yield 0
    while True:
        yield from range(base_factor, 10 * base_factor, base_factor)
        base_factor *= 10

def count_by_powers_of_ten(limit):
    result = list()
    for number in base_ten_log_counter():
        result.append(number)
        if number >= limit:
            break

    return result

print(count_by_powers_of_ten(1000))
```

And running the code does yield the result you'd expect.

> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]`

Additionally, if you wanted to pack everything into just a limited generator, you could do that like this. This is especially useful if your definition of 'efficient' includes memory usage. The generator pattern is very memory efficient (especially for calls with large limits) because it will just calculate the values on the fly.

If you were to throw this generator into that performance test that @Kelly Bundy put together, it'd come out at around third.

```py
def base_ten_log_generator(limit):
    base_factor = 1
    yield 0
    under_limit = limit > 0
    while under_limit:
        for value in range(base_factor, 10 * base_factor, base_factor):
            yield value
            if value >= limit:
                under_limit = False
                break
        base_factor *= 10
```

you can still access the same values here, but if you want them all at once, they've gotta be passed into a list:

```
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(0)))
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(1)))
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(10)))
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(11)))
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(100)))
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(101)))
print(list(base_ten_log_generator(1000)))
```

produces the results:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark with input `1000`:

```
  1.78 ± 0.02 μs  Kelly_2
  1.94 ± 0.07 μs  Kelly_1
  3.80 ± 0.12 μs  David_2
  4.09 ± 0.09 μs  Kelly_4
  4.66 ± 0.19 μs  Kelly_3
  4.92 ± 0.13 μs  Noel
  5.51 ± 0.19 μs  David_1
 13.18 ± 0.43 μs  original

Mike failed 12340 times, first on input 2
```

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVdNbuM2FN5r0TO8ogtLjia1nUzQGqPZtCgQFJ3NdGcYgmyRCRGJEigqkzTISbqZTbvvflY9QA_Q05S_IinLaSYYLxKJ7_f73uOj-Puf7T2_bujHj3_0HL_67t-v3mHW1MBJjQgHUrcN4-YtUpKOF5x0nOw7K61RQVOxXqJbrVIX_NoKq-ZquYiiqEQYGkauCC2qmNC25znt6x1iyToC8SMY_FXIMlhoifwxxHtGYbPYqqVKJJA32Oh2kAlJCkst3PeMITo4EsKlWv9wTSo0lr4JorqAbfMBMRmCIyo8EMpjhSQO7ZNksCB0z1AtRbt7GXMB83ngZtAcpXCSBbaD2gjkadG2iJbjBCKPnpGFYf1nVFX3-XKKdIa6vuKKPs0dGbFF5gLHm-wIScZcAGAFvUIxSZWB-OvRAnNJRnRM33N8QgZLA0gb-DBWL4IRX8I6U7kln4XmcgQlg8svBeTsWUDsZgBNoGqnEbb_aWTXZMrYgcHgdpr2Oxd1coYuniugy9F240QXHmI9fzHWFCi64_mAO7WZfDnsLsAUdl8eiL28XsiPIuhdg6q4Lu5CbpqeOzydx1HHUZt35Dc0NIFa2Tc95SrbV6upGSg5fWoGugQcB4HjExvO0BdGzeD7kDuXZsjNRMImsYmkRczBz6ATMnNsJvp0hxaG9h-LW1KKmViRmvBxQ8oxGuuS4YbZViEUdkWH5CTPxVFgIcTJeIJMlT7surcyhggckrZjqLiZaBSZ71ORlQwXe9640XBPUFWCv1V-ZT1y8bRcHdZ6gnlOUnV2QbDivThAfmBdZ5_c1YhcfYDPAyRXiCJWCHujuz0EO1Z5HuaeluLcVRZgyIa3AR-ehqNFlvu2qHokq_3ZxITl1Okob8G6aAMdYroLDrP_qag6dKDjuuWpUvxCbtDx4etPlmd9fxkztSxnRsNKtYnd51EQy9tDjtBFOlgebB2ZkH06gc2tOpLmc6oL43wsU3GSbw_3irLSX15DkK2gAvd0L33bD9DUfhTZh5V9OLMP56mazakdFfZBaEpSo-gb-KERU2fPKeo6aAvxrbuMMGHiEwwXpBLRHh4j-dSZx5CG5ers_MIQgO5a4cfLL6aOOlkXUADW_ijBQge-zoztetxiYtY0XFnKDA5bzCW6wVt5yh1qSEMtXAZCJNpxwqFVV0eFJXyDRxgOc9tKKt-3CJWRvGYotvAaNtuR5aNqaHn76GJsiNMdzGWboAulr_x24uKByli5Eyklm_XrbdAtePYgLy0x75L1xekKP8Lff8GDusGotXO19s-nDmaRKlzuCrd6bYIfK44spL4wxVVR78piLYq1XCwWSWoOgEy9wbcg_zs7k649P3iiY2MPkgqVwg26zxQTJpWWyR1ouUkBn-Y5LWqU58lko64ibZG4AF6faJnzkcJMSlE5S4cyizWVb6o7CRqqx8csDVsr0ddKc7u0t8z_AA)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from math import log10


def original(input_number):
    if input_number == 0:
        return [0]
    list_of_numbers = [0, 1]
    current_number  = 1
    while current_number < input_number:
        power_of_ten = int(log10(current_number))
        increment_by = 10 ** power_of_ten
        current_number += increment_by
        list_of_numbers.append(current_number)
    return list_of_numbers


def Kelly_1(input_number):
    result = [0]
    i = 1
    while i*10 <= input_number:
        result += range(i, i*10, i)
        i *= 10
    result += range(i, input_number+i, i)
    return result

def Kelly_2(input_number):
    result = [0]
    i = 1
    while (I := i*10) <= input_number:
        result += range(i, I, i)
        i = I
    result += range(i, input_number+i, i)
    return result

def Kelly_3(input_number):
    result = [0]
    number = 0
    power = 1
    while number < input_number:
        number += power
        if number == power * 10:
            power *= 10
        result.append(number)
    return result

def Kelly_4(input_number):
    result = [0]
    number = 0
    power, next_power = 1, 10
    while number < input_number:
        number += power
        if number == next_power:
            power = next_power
            next_power *= 10
        result.append(number)
    return result


def Noel(max_number):
    output_numbers = [0]
    step_size = 1
    step_counter = -2
    current_number = 0

    while current_number < max_number:
        step_counter += 1
        if step_counter == 9:
            step_size *= 10
            step_counter = 0

        current_number += step_size
        output_numbers.append(current_number)

    return output_numbers


def David_1(limit):
    result = list()
    for number in base_ten_log_counter():
        result.append(number)
        if number >= limit:
            break
    return result
def base_ten_log_counter():
    base_factor = 1
    yield 0
    while True:
        yield from range(base_factor, 10 * base_factor, base_factor)
        base_factor *= 10


def David_2(limit):
    return [*base_ten_log_generator(limit)]
def base_ten_log_generator(limit):
    base_factor = 1
    yield 0
    under_limit = limit > 0
    while under_limit:
        for value in range(base_factor, 10 * base_factor, base_factor):
            yield value
            if value >= limit:
                under_limit = False
                break
        base_factor *= 10


def Mike(input_number):
    results = [0]
    if input_number == 0:
        return results
    max_order = int(log10(input_number))
    for n in range(0,max_order):
        results = results + [v * 10**n for v in range(1,10)]
    return results + [10 ** max_order]


funcs = original, Kelly_1, Kelly_2, Kelly_3, Kelly_4, Noel, David_1, David_2, Mike

# Correctness part 1
first_fail = {}
fails = {}
for n in range(12346):
    expect = original(n)
    for f in funcs:
        if f(n) != expect:
            if f not in fails:
                first_fail[f] = n
                fails[f] = 1
            else:
                fails[f] += 1
funcs = [f for f in funcs if f not in fails]

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} μs '

for _ in range(25):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(1000), number=1000) / 1000
        times[f].append(t)

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

# Correctness part 2
print()
for f in fails:
    print(f.__name__, 'failed', fails[f], 'times, first on input', first_fail[f])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding ranges:

```
def count_by_powers_of_ten(input_number):
    result = [0]
    i = 1
    while i*10 <= input_number:
        result += range(i, i*10, i)
        i *= 10
    result += range(i, input_number+i, i)
    return result
```

The multiple `* 10` could be optimized, for example:

```
def count_by_powers_of_ten(input_number):
    result = [0]
    i = 1
    while (I := i*10) <= input_number:
        result += range(i, I, i)
        i = I
    result += range(i, input_number+i, i)
    return result
```

Two different ways:

```
def count_by_powers_of_ten(input_number):
    result = [0]
    number = 0
    power = 1
    while number < input_number:
        number += power
        if number == power * 10:
            power *= 10
        result.append(number)
    return result
```

```
def count_by_powers_of_ten(input_number):
    result = [0]
    number = 0
    power, next_power = 1, 10
    while number < input_number:
        number += power
        if number == next_power:
            power = next_power
            next_power *= 10
        result.append(number)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may be a case of premature optimization, here is a more optimized solution to your problem:

```py
def count_by_powers_of_ten(max_number):
    output_numbers = [0]
    step_size = 1
    step_counter = -2
    current_number = 0

    while current_number < max_number:
        step_counter += 1
        if step_counter == 9:
            step_size *= 10
            step_counter = 0

        current_number += step_size
        output_numbers.append(current_number)

    return output_numbers
```

This achieves your task without relying on calculating the logarithm each iteration of the loop. It timed the execution (using the inbuilt `timeit` module) times of your and my functions and saw a ~45% reduction in time:

```py
Your function: 5.3563193
Optimized function: 2.958699 (-45%)
```

The optimized solution works by counting the iterations since the last "jump" in powers of ten was made and then increasing the step-amount. That said, this is *an optimized* solution, not *the optiomal* solution.

Comment: now doesn't fail for input 0 anymore :)

Comment: @KellyBundy just included a wrong solution set in my testing suite. Fixed it now :)

Comment: Ok, seems correct now, according to my testing (it produces the same results as the original for all inputs from 0 to 12345).

Comment: *"wrong solution set in my testing suite"* - Does that mean you wrote some selected inputs and outputs? I find it much simpler and safer to just compare results with the reference implementation on all inputs up to some size...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with list comprehension and ranges:

```py
def generate_powers(input_number):
    results = [0]
    if input_number == 0:
        return results
    max_order = int(log10(input_number))
    max_factor = int(input_number / 10**max_order)
    for n in range(0,max_order):
        results.extend([v * 10**n for v in range(1,10)])
    return results + [v * 10 ** max_order for v in range(1, 1+max_factor)]
```

Although the edge case code (i.e. adding the final few max_order values) makes it not appreciably faster:

```
print(timeit(lambda: count_by_powers_of_ten(1000), number=100000))
print(timeit(lambda: generate_powers(1000), number=100000))
```

Yields the following values on my machine:

```
0.5146400999999999
0.4942310999999999
```

Comment: It came from your original version not giving the correct results.

Comment: Downvotes are for actually wrong code, not for typos. If you spot a typo, just leave a comment to get it fixed =)

Comment: Even if I agreed with that, how am I supposed to know what's a typo? If it gives wrong results, it's wrong code. I did point out failure cases for the other three answers before yours, but enough is enough. Four answers all initially wrong. People should test.

Comment: Actually it's still wrong (I forgot I had modified my testing to test something special).

Comment: Turns out I _did_ test, and was updating my post because of that. Also "how am I supposed to know what's a typo": by reading the code instead of just copy-pasting it? No one's paying you to review, that's all you, if you feel burdened by having to double check everyone's code, don't. There are thousands of potential others who will comment and up/downvote over the course of a post's lifetime =)

Comment: That said, going "it's still wrong" and then not saying _how_ it's still wrong is fairly useless. Either say what's wrong, or don't bother with that claim. It doesn't help improve the answer, _even if yours is better already_.

Comment: Well like I said, enough is enough. At some point I don't feel like pointing out the failure cases anymore. It's trivial to test and find out yourself. But ok, for the first time, I've expanded my testing/benchmarking code to include and show failures. First input yours fails is 2.

Comment: Thanks: if you'd simply said "this still fails on 2, you probably want to run some more tests for 1..99" or the like, I could have updated the code an hour ago instead of after us having to go through this discussion. "Enough is enough" is a really weird thing to say when we're all volunteers here, and no one expects you to verify every single answer _unless you're the OP_ in which case, that's literally your part of the Stackoverflow deal =)

Comment: And before you go "it's still wrong and I don't care to tell you why", yes: it intentionally generates one fewer elements for certain inputs because generating "100" when the input is "99" or "2000" for "1001" is almost certainly the wrong behaviour, but that's for the OP to explain in their post comment thread.

Comment: If you knowingly deviate from theirs (which they say *"does exactly what I was wanting it to do"* and which is perfectly reasonable), you'd better mention that. Why would generating 100 be wrong if input is 99? Going only up to 90 like you do, 99 is then outside the range. With 100, it's covered.